# How to make a generic type an union type of Record<K,V> and an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to declare a couple singleton class (Angular service) that *must* have some members named after an enum. Until now I had it as a const:

```
enum RewardId {
  HEHE = 'AdMobRewardIdHEHE',
  HOHO = 'AdMobRewardIdHOHO',
}

interface RewardObject {
  id: RewardId;
  someData: any
}


const MyConst: Record<RewardId, RewardObject> = {
  [RewardId.HEHE]: {
    id: RewardId.HEHE,
    someData: 'someData'
  },

  [RewardId.HOHO]: {
    id: RewardId.HOHO,
    someData: 'someData'
  }
}
```

If I add a new `RewardId` Typescript lets me know that I have to implement it on `MyConst` **this is what I want**

[image]
[Typescript Playground link][2]

Now, I want to change it to a service (so a class) because it is easier to test and I also need some methods there.

```
interface VaultMethods {
   someMethod1(): void;
  someMethod2(): void;
}

class MyClass implements Record<RewardId, RewardObject>, VaultMethods {
  [RewardId.HEHE] = {
    id: RewardId.HEHE,
    someData: 'someData'
  };

  [RewardId.HOHO] = {
    id: RewardId.HOHO,
    someData: 'someData'
  };

  someMethod1() { }

  someMethod2() { }
}
```

[Typescript Playground][3]

As final step I need this to convert that class definition in a generic interface:

This does not work `interface Vault<K, V> extends VaultMethods, Record<K, V>` because `An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.`

If I make it a type it kind of works in the way that Typescript ask me to implement the methods and members

```
type Vault<K, V> = Record<K, V> & VaultMethods;
class MyClass2 implements Vault<RewardId, RewardObject> {

}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=68&ssc=2&pln=49&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBASsDuBDATgEwJKqgbwLACgooAJAUTKgF4oByAQVQFkB7AIziTUzLJoBoCRYgHkRVWgxbsEKDKhEj+BAgF9l+AJYgALsGQAzRAGNgsGWmGsAVsCPacgqBtQAuM5zkBuRwGdmEYAARRG1EN0QQAE9VdSNmEB97RkiAYXjEtzg4tAAeDllMPndZSxs7AD5xPEIoAG18rlQAOh5SAF03aqIiZ0zzORbyUgEaoj8A4NC3GnGgkMQaRxURx3r+zBbRYQ6HUadXYsbNkRHuqFnJsNoL+cWatXwH9S1dA2NTADVEMAAbbUZgNoABbMVA+XbdWYA4GggCMAAoAJRuABuzGc3hqUMBINQACYkaj0ahMU98EYfogfODkilKdSnBAAA4-YABHTgrLMXINORFXmlWzacpFL6-f440Hgrp1XkbVptKqOHoHOXNVqnSH+OZTa7ay53IgqTGrNXHbZKva9Q4DBTCTVjfXzaY3UKGqDG9SOgLQ3EIxE4D1e87a32ggkB7BBx7qAgAejjiWQWgA5lBgAAPXQgMFQAAqUAA-IHagAFJwgfM7NEYj1QNx5zxEBNQUjIZDc9TaSJMz7fP5c3IAaXTWdAuYA1sBIsx9FAIpEinnKtQZUQyxWoEOdo3VCb8N3e1AxX8ckPRSvj-3tIPUGeL1AAGRX8VhsH7ilUmmpek+PGMlk2VAbRwRPbQ8nWVB+X6QUKghWVIMGMhFVXZV9j6Dx5SGB0QwmZ09Twt0ln3dczTtFD4JVDCCnVLYcNdK4ZidIj7hI71gDff0cE9LFQ0lfEkW40kgA)
[image: as type]

But It shows an error in the Type Definition:
[image: error in the Type Definition]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Update your typescript playground links: the last two do not actually show the code you are working with.

Comment: @Terry sorry Looks like I broke the post text limit. I just let the "latest" one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you were missing a constraint on type parameter `K`. Since you're passing it to `Record` and that the K is probably an enum, you can say that `K` extends `string`.

```
type Vault<K extends string, V> = Record<K, V> & VaultMethods;
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=28&pln=17&pc=13#code/KYOwrgtgBASsDuBDATgEwJKqgbwLACgooAJAUTKgF4oByAQVQFkB7AIziTUzLJoBoCRYgHkRVWgxbsEKDKhEj%20gqAHoVxOhvH0mbDrO6a6S-AF8CBAJYgALsGQAzRAGNgsGWmGsAVsGc2cZUtUAC53TjkAbmUAZ2YIYAARRBtEMMQQAE8Cc3wrW3snVygANUQwABsbRmAbAAtmVBjAwiI4hJr6xoBGAAoASjCAN2Zg6Nb24E6G1AAmAeHR1HHcghtMgAc3MsqbAB4AaShgAA87ECaoGJtkawBzPlKAPnE4Z2Y0Q8eSl4AyUvKVWmjRi4wIzgqiBizUYmQAwpDoVBLBANhVgAlbM0dlU9vouKhHvjUF5fP4XnhWgBtYmYAB0PFIAF1xJSiERgmFaagGeRSAJWm14kkUmlaJNkqkaMpTGDqdyGaJhCzqGz2ZzwgYeQphAL2VdhZKxTQJaLpa1ZRYJsLgag%20v0cFBVtaOrUZvMHdgnTkCEA)